# Basemap is not showing up in AGOL when sharing from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps

Beginner Question: In my map that I shared from ArcGIS Pro into AGOL all of the layers shows up but Basemap not. Basemap that I am using in ArcGIS Pro is a WMTS Layer which I am saving as Basemap but still it doesnt appear in AGOL. What could be the issue ? I am using organisation account with 'publisher' licence. I am not getting any error when sharing it during the analyse.

Comment: What projection is your data in? normally this is Web Mercator.

Comment: My data are in UTM 32. The Basemap as well.... In ArcGIS Pro there is no shift at all between layers and Basemap and in AGOL it doesnt appear at all not even in the list of standard Basemaps in AGOL

Comment: If the basemap you are using in ArcPro is a [WMTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Tile_Service) then why not add that as a layer in the AGOL map. As I understand it basemaps in ArcPro don't "upload" when you share you data.

Comment: this is what I tried yesterday but it didnt work and it didnt show any error, simply didnt appear but now it works! I assume yesterday WMTS service was not working. Thanks a lot for your contribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to reload the basemap from AGOL.

- Publish from Arcgis pro
- Open the map in Arcgis online
- Add the WMTS layer from the external server

At least what I have done for this case.

Sometimes the coordinate systems are not the same, and AGOL will reject the connection if WMTS is different from the basemap.

Comment: Coordinate System is my case seems to be not a problem I have my data and Basemap in UTM32 I symply tried again and now it works.. Maybe yesterday WMTS was not available and what is worth to mention is that WMTS Basemap is not going to be shown on the standard list of the basemaps in AGOL

Comment: Exactly, for ArcGIS if it is not part of AGOL basemaps, is not considered a basamap is considered just a normal layer. I suppose if you make custom basemaps and you include the WTMS layer as one of your custom basemaps, it may be available at organisation basemaps. I will test it in future :D